# Aber vs noch vs doch?

Tags: preposition

What are the differences between these three words given that all three have similar meanings (in that they can all mean "but").

Comment: Welcome to German Language! This site isn't a translation service. Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Questions ask here should show a certain level of previous effort. What you should do first is look up these words in a good dictionary that has explanations and sample sentences. With problems still unsolved you are welcome to come back here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the following will help you:

> aber: though (options: however, but)
>
> noch: still (options: even, only, more)
>
> doch: nevertheless (options:  yet, all the same, though)